# Enabling "permanent" login in firebase anonymously in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, persistence

I'd like to know if it's possible to keep that login permanent unless the user finishes everything that would be related to that login, like I guess, powering off the phone, killing all services with that login or the like.

It looks like it's possible to set the persistence as desired, [as shown here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence), but in a browser session and I'd need it for an Android app. Guess the similar one for firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL would fulfill my needs.

Maybe it's also possible that Firebase already does that on its own but I cannot find clear information about that, so I'd better ask here.

Is there any way to do this?

PD: I'm trying to explain better:

In my app I use services that can read form firebase at any moment, but after some time it's been initiated and user autheticated then it does not read more data.

I've tried to solve it by including this countdowtimer in the services to periodically try to reload the connection:

```
      mkc=new CountDownTimer(1500000000,600000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long l) {


                    waitforfirebaselogin(); //custom function that logs into firebase

                    (code that perform when login is achieved)
}
mkc.start();
```

But for some reason that countdowtimer is never executed.

Maybe a service with an infinite loop that tries to reconnect may work.

Answer (score 0):

When you sign the user into an Android app anonymously with Firebase Authentication, the information for that user's identity is stored on disk. When the app restarts, that identity is automatically restored.

The only ways to lose the anonymous user's identity is to sign them out, sign in a different user, or to *delete* the app from the device.

Comment: Thanks, @Frank van Puffelen, but my point is not about restoring the connection when app restarts, it's more about having a permanent, or at the very least semipermanent continous connection, as my app needs services that can read from firebase at any moment. I'm editing my question to make it more clear